# Is there an error in this solution - poisson formula for the ball

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am looking at the following. I wonder if the highlighted is an error? Is the second $\leq$ meant to be a $\geq$?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct that it should be $\geq$ in the displayed equation.

Comment: @Chappers Thanks, I was hoping I wasn't mad!